# Fill LaravelCollective select with data from DB

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravelcollective

I'm using LaravelCollective because of the benefits that Form Model Binding offers.

My problem is that I need to fill a select with Categories from the Database so I'm making something like this:

```
{!! Form::select('size', Category::pluck('name'), null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a category...']) !!}
```

The problem with this is that the first option generated has value="0".

I'm looking for a Eloquent way to generate an array ['key' => 'value'] where key is the Id and value is the name. I know I could make a method, get all the categories and generate the Array myself but this isnt what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Category::pluck('name', 'id')`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk it worked. Add the answer so I can vote it. Why do I have to write name before id?

Comment: @Alan That's how `pluck` works - it get's a collection of values (1st param) with optional keys (2nd param). If 2nd is not provided, then it will have simple array keys, starting with `0`

Comment: @Alan pluck signature is `pluck($column, $key = null)`

Comment: I would recommend putting the `Category::pluck('name', 'id')` in your controller, then referencing it in your view.